# handling image size in iOS

Tags: ios, image, ipad

In my app a user can attach an image which is then uploaded.  The problem is that when they attach multiple pictures it can slow the app significantly. Is there away that I can reduce the image quality so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want some image processing.

Example library for that task:
http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/